# Error with using AppConfig

Tags: .net, vb.net, app-config

I have a problem with access to string variable from AppSettings. Here is the code which generates a well known error: *Object reference  not set to an instance of an object*

```
Dim folderName As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LogFolder").ToString()
```

And here is an App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        ...
    </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    ...
  </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <applicationSettings>
        <BazyPolaczenia.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="LogFile" serializeAs="String">
                <value>"log.txt"</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="LogFolder" serializeAs="String">
                <value>"d:\Logs"</value>
            </setting>
        </BazyPolaczenia.My.MySettings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have added `Imports System.Configuration`. What is wrong with that line?

Comment: Because you don't have an appSettings configuration section containing an "add" element with the key LogFolder, you are calling ToString() on a null reference.

Comment: `applicationSettings` is definitely <> `appSettings`

Comment: Yeah now I'm reading the difference between `applicationSettings` and `appSettings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config file is not right:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    ...
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="LogFile" value="log.txt" />
    <add key="LogFolder" value="d:\Logs" />
  </appSettings>
 <connectionStrings>
  ...
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And if you are running a website you'd need this in your web.config or in the app.config of the entry point project (e.g. the project that is executed)